# AutoMapper, SelectMany i'm getting various elements numbers

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm very new to AutoMapper and I'm trying to get a list of Flatten classes.
But my code gives my various numbers of elements in the list.
F.e. I should get 710 elements, sometimes it works fine, but usually, the list contains 300-600 elements.
I would be grateful for any ideas.

```
 var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<RGMMainRecipe, RGMMainRecipeDTO>();
            cfg.CreateMap<RGMPhaseRecipe, RGMPhaseRecipeFlatDTO>();
            cfg.CreateMap<RGMRecipeValue, RGMPhaseRecipeFlatDTO>();
            cfg.CreateMap<Variable, RGMPhaseRecipeFlatDTO>();
        });

        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        List<RGMPhaseRecipeFlatDTO> phases = null;

        phases = rgm.Phases.SelectMany
                (
                    p => p.ValueItems.Select(mapper.Map<RGMRecipeValue, 
                                     RGMPhaseRecipeFlatDTO>)
                                      .Select(d => mapper.Map(p, d))
                                    ).ToList();
```